# JavaFX Bindings based on Bindings.size() is not getting triggered

Tags: javafx, observable

Yes, the problem is very similar to [an old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41174088/3079849) asked a few years ago.  In fact, my sample code is based on that one, too.  I also tried the answer given there but it didn't work.

Here is the sample code:

```
package com.example.bindingssize;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.BooleanBinding;
import javafx.beans.binding.IntegerBinding;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {

    private IntegerBinding sizeBinding;
    private BooleanBinding isEven;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Demonstrator");

        // Button
        Button addButton = new Button();
        addButton.setText("Add Element");
        addButton.setOnAction(event -> list.add("TEST"));

        // ListView
        ListView<String> lv = new ListView<>();
        lv.setItems(list);

        // Add elements to root
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().add(addButton);
        root.getChildren().add(lv);

        // Show scene
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();

        sizeBinding = Bindings.size(list);

        isEven = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> {
            System.out.println(sizeBinding.get()); // key line 1 of 2
            System.out.println("inside isEven");
            return list.size() % 2 == 0;
        }, sizeBinding);

        // key line 2 of 2
        isEven.addListener((obs, o, n) -> System.out.println(isEven.get() ? "Even" : "Odd"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

The above code works.  Each time the add button is clicked, the print statements inside 'isEven' print as expected.  However, this behavior completely depends on the 2 key lines.  The print statement won't print anything if one or both of the key lines is missing.  Here I made everything a field of the class, so they shouldn't be garbage collected.  So what's the reason of this behavior?

This is JavaFX 11.0.2, AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9, on macOS Catalina.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Bindings Are Lazy

In JavaFX, a binding has a "valid" state. When the value is potentially changed while the binding is in a valid state then the binding fires an invalidation event. But if the binding is not currently valid then no invalidation event will be fired. The way to "validate" a binding is to query its value. This setup allows a binding to compute its value only when that value is needed.

### Depending On Bindings

Your `isEven` binding is dependent on the `sizeBinding` binding. This is implemented by having the `isEven` binding observe the `sizeBinding` binding via an `InvalidationListener`. As noted above, invalidation events are only fired when a binding goes from a valid state to an invalid state.

The problem is, except for your `println(sizeBinding.get())` call, you never query the value of `sizeBinding`. That means you never validate the binding, and that means the `isEven` binding never knows to recompute its value. If you had:

```java
isEven = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> sizeBinding.get() % 2 == 0, sizeBinding);
```

Then it would work. Notice it queries the `sizeBinding` value.

### Change Listeners

If a `ChangeListener` is added to a binding then the value is computed eagerly. The reason for this is simple: The listener is passed both the old *and new* values. Without the `ChangeListener` you add to the `isEven` binding, the binding remains lazy. And since you never validate the `isEven` binding it never needs to (re)compute its value.

With the `ChangeListener` added, however, the value is (re)computed eagerly. But note the `isEven` binding will only recompute its value if it knows that value has changed. In other words, you still have to make sure the `sizeBinding` binding is validated when appropriate.